# How to execute javascript in django 1.6.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have defined class Media as:

```
class LtAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = LtForm
    class Media:
        js = ('javascript/lt/showhid_follow_up.js',)
```

This javascript code lies in django project folder:

> /home/myself/mysite/static/javascript/lt/showhid_follow_up.js

settings.py contains:

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Javascript is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    alert('Hi');
});
```

Do I have to define MEDIA_URL to use this? Do I have to have a src in the javascript? If I add  and , it displays error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

On removing this, error I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jQuery' of object [object Object] is not
>   a function

How do I resolve this problem? I have tried using FireFox as well as Chrome browsers
Am I missing some other settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is included already in Django admin, it's just under the `django` namespace. Passing in `django.jQuery` using an immediately invoking function allows you to use the more familiar `$` shortcut instead of having to write `django.jQuery` all the time.

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        alert('Hi');
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

Comment: I am using the modelAdmin from django, no other template. How do I use  jquery? What should be the path, I am totally a noob at this http://stackoverflow.com/users/598683/brandon, plz guide

Comment: No worries. I've updated my answer with specific details about how to access jQuery within Django Admin.